# How to make gcc optimize function call with constant parameters at compile time?

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to parse user input and execute some tasks according to the commands given by user. As, in C, switch doesn't work with strings I have decided to use switch of hash values of strings to compare which command to execute.

Now, as maintaining the list of all hashes of all available commands in something like this

```
#define EXIT 6385204799
...
```

is really tedious task, I was wandering if there exist way to convince `gcc` to evaluate the hash function with constant parameter on compile time so I could use something like this

```
switch(hash(command)){
    case hash("exit"): exit();
    // I know, case labels must be compile time constants
    // but that should be fulfilled in my case
}
```

I know I could use for example metaprogramming but I am interested more in the solution with gcc.

Is it even possible?

```
#include <stdio.h>


unsigned long hash(const char *str)
{
        unsigned long hash = 5381;
        int c;

        while ((c = *str++))
                hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c;
        return hash;
}

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
        char *command=NULL;
        size_t size=0;
        printf("Enter string:");
        getline(&command, &size, stdin);
        printf("%ld",hash("exit")); // I want this to evaluate in compile time
        printf("%ld",hash(command)); // and this not
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is nearly impossible. You want the *optimizer* to *run* your non-trivial code and evaluate the result. It is not designed this way.

Comment: @davmac Interesting. Will take a look at the proof once on a desktop...

Comment: @EugeneSh. my original answer was wrong - editing now. Clang can do it, but GCC cannot.

Comment: @davmac The problem that I see with that is that if you write a function, say, to brute force some constant strong crypto hash, then by this approach the compilation will take forever to complete.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I assume that there is some limit as to how many times the compiler will unroll a loop, etc, to avoid this problem. In this case the string "exit" is short and it only needs to unroll a single loop with four iterations. (That said, the compiler manages with significantly longer strings as well).

Comment: If only this question would be tagged C++...

Comment: You could write a program that generates the hashes in the header, that your build systems runs prior to C compilation

Comment: @M.M: your suggestion is probably what the OP refers to as *metaprogramming*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it even possible?

GCC cannot (for C - it can for C++, see below), but Clang/LLVM (version 3.9.1) can. Use the `-O2` switch to enable level 2 optimisations (or higher).

[Proof](https://godbolt.org/g/PyEGAU). See the disassembly - there is no call to a hash function, no loop; the compiler has calculated the hash at compile time. This reduced form of your test case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static unsigned long hash(const char *str)
{
        unsigned long hash = 5381;
        int c;

        while ((c = *str++))
                hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c;
        return hash;
}

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
        size_t size=0;
        printf("%ld",hash("exit")); // I want this to evaluate in compile time
        return 0;
}
```

Compiles to:

```
main:                                   # @main
# BB#0:
        push    rax
        #DEBUG_VALUE: main:argc <- %EDI
        #DEBUG_VALUE: main:argv <- %RSI
        #DEBUG_VALUE: main:size <- 0
        movabs  rsi, 6385204799
        mov     edi, .L.str
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rcx
        ret

.L.str:
        .asciz  "%ld"
```

The line `movabs  rsi, 6385204799` directly loads the pre-calculated hash value into the `rsi` register.

However, the value will not be considered a compile-time constant for purposes of use in a `case` label in a `switch` statement. You need to use `if ... else` for comparison rather than `switch`.

In case you are interested, with modern C++ you can achieve this type of optimisation using GCC as well as Clang/LLVM, and you can even use a `switch` statement:

```
#include <cstdio>

static constexpr unsigned long hash(const char *str)
{
        unsigned long hash = 5381;
        int c = *str;

        while ((c = *str++))
                hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c;
        return hash;
}

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
        size_t size=0;
        printf("%ld",hash("exit")); // I want this to evaluate in compile time

        switch((unsigned long)5 /* i.e. some number */) {
        case hash("exit"):
            // etc
            ;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

This is C++14 code, you will need to use `-std=c++14` to compile it (or use GCC 6+ for which this is the default). (Of course, the code is not idiomatic C++ - it is intended to be as close as possible to the previous example).

Comment: Very impressive a compiler will simulate a loop it knows has purely constant inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a C program which will rely on your `hash` function and which will generate your header definition file based on a configuration file.

config file: `EXIT "exit"` -> process config file -> header file (commands.h): `#define EXIT 6385204799`

Then you can include `commands.h` in your program in use the enum in your switch statement.

```
switch(hash(command)){
    case EXIT: exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:
If 4 characters are enough you could use literals like 'exit' / 'tixe' (depending on endianness) instead of a hash function.  Note the single quotes.

Any way to make it a constant expression will be compiler dependent anyhow, so you might be able to use [gcc's statement expression extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) that allows macros to return a value.  It looks like `({int hash=5381; /*do stuff*/ hash;})` ... but you may need to `#pragma GCC push_options` `#pragma GCC optimize ("unroll-loops")` before your case statements and `#pragma GCC pop_options` after.

One alternative is to map strings to enums and use a binary search of the alphabetized strings instead of a hash.  You can use an X-macro to simplify adding and removing commands.  In this example I used it for function  prototypes and case statements as well (not necessary, just easier to work with for a simple example)

```
#include <string.h>
#define MYXMACRO(OP) \
  OP(bar) \
  OP(exit) \
  OP(foo)

#define AS_ENUM(x,...) MYENUM_##x,
enum { MYXMACRO(AS_ENUM) MYENUMCOUNT };
#undef AS_ENUM

#define AS_STRING(x,...) #x,
const char* mystrings[]= { MYXMACRO(AS_STRING) };
#undef AS_STRING

#define AS_PROTOTYPES(x,...) void do_##x(void);
MYXMACRO(AS_PROTOTYPES)
void do_default(void);
#undef AS_PROTOTYPES

int mybsearch(const char *command){
    size_t bot=0, top=MYENUMCOUNT, i=((bot+top)>>1)&(~1);
    int cmp;
    for (; bot<=top && i<=MYENUMCOUNT; i=((bot+top)>>1)&(~1)){
        cmp=strcmp(command,mystrings[i]);
        if (! cmp) return i; //match found
        else if (cmp>0) bot=i+1;
        else top=i-1;
    }
    return -1;
}

void do_command(const char * command){
#define AS_CASE(x,...)  case MYENUM_##x : do_##x(__VA_ARGS__);break;
  switch(mybsearch(command)){
    MYXMACRO(AS_CASE)
    default: do_default();
  }
}
#undef MYXMACRO
```